# CUPS gives 'Unable to open the initial device, quitting' when printing to network printer

Tags: printing, cups

I am trying to print over Wi-Fi to an HP Photosmart D110 printer which is successfully recognized by CUPS. But I only get a sheet with the error message `Unable to open the initial device, quitting`. And in the CUPS interface it says `Filter failed`.

At home I have an HP Photosmart C3100 that works correctly over USB, so I think CUPS is not the problem. I have tried to no avail:

- reinstalling `cups`/`hplip`
- `pacman -S avahi nss-mdns` (like proposed [here](http://foro.desdelinux.net/viewtopic.php?id=963))

The full text of `/var/log/cups/error_log` is [here](http://pastebin.com/nSMaS7dS). The same printer works correctly over USB, too.

I'm running Arch Linux x86-64 with cups 1.6.1. What am I missing?

Comment: Versions of cups on your machine and the server?

Comment: I'm not using a print server (the printer has its own embedded print server). cups on my machine is 1.6.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by using the `hpcups` driver rather than the `hpijs` one (picked when configuring the printer).